# Swagger Codegen CLI 2.3.1 not generating model properties with type of "array"

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

My model definition looks like this:

`swagger: '2.0'
definitions:
  Foo:
    type: object
    properties:
      fooProp1:
        type: string
      fooProp2:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Bar'
  Bar:
    type: object
    properties:
      blah:
        type: string`

I used Swagger Codegen CLI 2.3.1 to generate both Java models for backend and TypeScript models for frontend. In both cases, in the Foo class, there is only the property "fooProp1", but no "fooProp2". I expected something like

`private List<Bar> fooProp2;`

would be in generated Java model classes.

What did I miss? Is there any problem in my Swagger code?? How should I modify my Swagger code to get my expected server/client model code?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: 1) Which exactly Java and TypeScript targets are you generating? (E.g. `jaxrs`, `jaxrs-resteasy`, etc.) 2) Your example is not valid - `type: object` should be inside `Foo:` rather than directly under `definitions:`. Paste your spec into http://editor.swagger.io to check and fix syntax errors.

Comment: @Helen, I was generating jaxrs-cxf target. Yes obejct should be inside Foo, it was a type error. I corrected it. Thank you!

Comment: Still not working like expected. No list property inside the generated Java and TypeScript code......